# Undefined local variable / no method error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can anyone explain to me why I am getting this error?  Rails is about conventions.  Is there a more conventional way of doing what I'm trying to do below?

```
undefined local variable or method `hello_world' for #<#<Class:...>:...>
```

Here are my files:

**welcome_controller.rb**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def hello_world
    "Hello, World"
  end
end
```

**welcome/index.html.erb**

```
<%= hello_world %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have you run through a Rails tutorial?

Comment: change subject - *how to call controller methods inside a view?*..suggestion..

Comment: I followed along with the Beginning Guide to Rails and the Code School Rails for Zombies, but I'm still confused. I thought I was doing it right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or do as :

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
 helper_method :hello_world
 def hello_world
    "Hello, World"
 end
end
```

Now call it inside the view :

```
<%= hello_world %>
```

Read [`helper_method`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method)

> Declare a controller method as a helper, to make the `hello_world` controller method available to the view.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, cause I don't really understand... if I wanted to do a basic hello world without the helper_method, SHOULD I have just created a class, and given hello_world inside the class? Reading up on helper_method now, but not sure why I need it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html) to allow you to write that in your ERB:

```
module WelcomeHelper

  def hello_world
     "Hello, World"
  end

end
```

and now, your ERB should work:

```
<%= hello_world %>
```

Comment: @UriAgassi inclusion of `WelcomeHelper` in Controller would only be required if OP wants to access `hello_world` in `Controller`.

Comment: @UriAgassi You need to use `helper WelcomeHelper` inside the controller.. Do that to make the answer complete, so that future readers not need to go and search it inside the doc..

Answer (score 2):

`hello_world` is action defined in controller and routes
You need to define variable(s) in your action. This variable(s) will be accessible in the view

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

 # this is action
 def index
    # this is variable
    @hello_world = "Hello, World"
 end

end

# view index.html.erb
# this calls variables defined in action
<%= @hello_world %>
```

**Update1:**

And if you define your route to `welcome#index` the action name in controller should be `index`!

Comment: This will not work unless you set the variable in `WelcomeController #index` action. As OP wants to access that particular value in `index.html.erb`. Change you action name to `index` instead of `hello_world`

Comment: @KirtiThorat instance variables can be used inside a view..why should it to be moved inside `#index` ?

Comment: Because OP is rendering `index.html.erb` and NOT `hello_world.html.erb`

Comment: @ArupRakshit Try it in any of your Rails application and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is more Rails-convention for you:

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "welcome#index"
resources :welcome

#app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
Class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
       #-> will render #app/views/welcome/index.html.erb
    end
end

#app/views/welcome/index.html.erb
Hello World
<%= hello_world %> <!-- Use `@Arup`'s answer to create a helper method -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use print 'ff'. it simply work for me :)